# Rewrite Rule for a Custom Post Type while having an existing page with the same name

Tags: wordpress

I have registered a custom post type "teacher" with slug "college/teacher". Now, when I try to access a post ("classA") which should be appear at college/teacher/classA is being thrown a 404 error. Though, there is already a page exists with title "teacher".

**Here is the code I used for Registering the custom post type:**

```
function teacher_item_section(){
// Custom Post Type Labels     
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Teacher', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Teacher', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Images' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Teacher' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Teacher' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Teachers' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Teacher' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Teachers' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No Teacher Found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Teacher Found' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Teacher' ),
    'menu_name'          => __( 'Teachers' )
);

// Custom Post Type Supports 
$supports = array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'revisions');

// Custom Post Type Arguments 
$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'hierarchical'       => true,
    'description'        => '',
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'  => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'  => true,
    'show_in_rest'       => true,
    'exclude_from_search'=> true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'can_export'         => true,
    'rewrite'              => array("slug" => "college/teacher"), // Permalinks format
    'has_archive'        => false,
    //'menu_position'      => 5,
    'supports'           => $supports,
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
);

register_post_type( 'teacher', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'teacher_item_section' );
```

**Also, I tried using rewrite URLs using following code but no luck yet.**

```
function colteacher_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'college/teacher/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?post_type=teacher&name=$matches][1]', 'top' );
    add_permastruct('teacher', 'college/teacher/%ateacher%' , version_compare($GLOBALS['wp_version'], '3.4', '<') ? false : array('with_front' => false));
}
add_action( 'init', 'colteacher_rewrite_rules', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: If you already have a page with the slug `teacher`, you shouldn't need the rewrite rules and the permastruct.

Could you try removing the `colteacher_rewrite_rules` function from `init`, and updating the permalinks?

Comment: @PetarPetrov I tried what you said and now it is throwing 404 error while I try to access single posts (domain.com/college/teacher/classA).

Comment: @PetarPetrov Actually the 2nd argument ('index.php?post_type=teacher&name=$matches][1]') of add_rewrite_rule() is the main suspect for me. But, I am not sure. May be you want to give a close look to it.

Comment: This is interesting, I copy-pasted your code (only the custom post type registration part) into a clean WordPress installation added a page with the name Teacher and updated the permalinks. I'll check the rewrite rules, but there should be no need for them, as WordPress can handle them out of the box.

Comment: Checking the code again - there are two errors. One is after the rewrite rule - `$matches]` (remove the `]`), and the other is `%ateacher%` - it should be `%teacher%`, as `teacher` is the custom post type.